# Получение элемента View вне класса активности с помощью ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife

Не могу понять, как получить доступ к элементу экрана не из класса активности. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Comment: уточните вопрос пожалуйста, приведите пример элемента и опишет что именно вам нужно, вопрос довольно расплывчатый

Comment: Скорее всего вы пытаетесь сделать что то такое, что делать не следует, так как доступ к View вне классов с ними работающих фактически бесполезен (примерно как просить принести монитор туда, где нужно посмотреть, что он показывает). Опишите подробнее, где именно вам требуется получить такой доступ и зачем, скорее всего ваша проблема решается по другому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это не Activity/Fragment/View c макетом, то вы никак не получите доступ к этому элементу экрана. Единственное, что вы можете сделать это из Activity/Fragment/View передать ссылку на вашу View в ваш класс.